# How many cookies can be set in one response?

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, cookies, httpresponse

Is there a maximum number of cookies which you can set on a single http response? If yes how many?

---

Because I'm trying to create 2 cookies in one response, for some reason only one is getting created. I'm using the code below.

```
Cookie cookie = new Cookie("wNote", "1530571761964");
cookie.setMaxAge(2592000);
cookie.setPath("/myWebsite/");
response.addCookie(cookie);
```

the other cookie is the `JSESSIONID` which is being created by the server automatically. In the response headers under `Set-Cookie` I can see only `JSESSIONID`.

- Apache Tomcat 8.0.27
- Google Chrome 67.0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using Tomcat then, **only one Cookie in HttpServletResponse.addCookie(javax.servlet.http.Cookie)** But this method can call multiple times:

> The servlet sends cookies to the browser by using the `HttpServletResponse.addCookie(javax.servlet.http.Cookie)` method, which adds fields to HTTP response headers to send cookies to the browser, **one at a time**.
>
> **This method can be called multiple times to set more than one cookie.**
>
> The browser is expected to support 20 cookies for each Web server, 300 cookies total, and may limit cookie size to 4 KB each.
>   
> <sub>[Cookies Doc](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/servletapi/javax/servlet/http/Cookie.html)</sub>

---

Ok going more deeper about this cookies. I check the [RFC 2109](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2109.txt)

> Practical user agent implementations have limits on the number and
>   size of cookies that they can store.  In general, user agents' cookie 
>   support should have no fixed limits.  They should strive to store as
>   many frequently-used cookies as possible.  Furthermore, general-use
>   user agents should provide each of the following minimum capabilities 
>   individually, although not necessarily simultaneously:
>
> - at least 300 cookies
> - at least 4096 bytes per cookie (as measured by the size of the
>         characters that comprise the cookie non-terminal in the syntax
>         description of the Set-Cookie header)
> - at least 20 cookies per unique host or domain name

Comment: I'm confused by this answer - the [Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse.html#addCookie-javax.servlet.http.Cookie-) specifically says `This method can be called multiple times to set more than one cookie`.  So with standard Java EE there is not set limit.  This has nothing directly to do with Tomcat.

Comment: @stdunbar You are correct it was confusing I edited the answer. YOu can only one Cookie in the servlet Response but you can call multiple Times.